# Working with Android Service

Tags: android

I am new to Android App development and I am trying to develop a Music Application but I need to have a good knowledge on Service,bind,unbind. I googled for more than 3 hours but could not understand because those are too complex code without proper explanation. So can anyone please help me to understand Service with proper and easy explanation ?

Comment: I would recommend starting with more basic Java and Android development and concepts until you understand what is going on. It shouldn't be super complex if you have a decent foundation. Just finding a quick example that you can piece together works for a single instance, but it doesn't help as much down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the other questions in this forum relating to the creation of a service, I am sure that there are a ton. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3kwFMkAsJ0&list=PL14AA2548E3C96B50) helped me when I was creating a music player for Android with a service. The tutorial is for an older version of Android, but the basic concepts are definitely transferable.